# Lambda Function NodeJS version always reverted to 12.x

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I am running javascript Lambda functions that required NodeJS version 14.x. I can manually set this in the AWS Lambda console here (screenshot below), but every time I use the amplify CLI to push a change of the function, it gets reverted back to 12.x. I can't find any reference to the NodeJS version in the local amplify files, or online. Is there a way to keep it from reverting every time?

This is what the Lambda console option looks like, which I edit to 14.x constantly, but it changes back to 12.x:
[image: 12.x on Lambda Console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @matsev's answer looks to be the official version supported by AWS, I noticed that while some of my functions continued to be reverted to 12.x, others stayed at 14.x even after a push. The ones that stayed at 14.x were my more recently created functions.

It turns out, **you can edit the *.cloudformation-template.json for each function to set the nodejs version**! This file did not appear in my vscode search due to a previous developer hiding it using `files.exclude`. This is likely a good best practice because the file is meant to be just edited using the amplify CLI, but there are obviously some settings that are not part of the CLI commands. Another example is the timeout parameter in here.

The file is located at: `amplify/backend/function/FUNCTION_NAME/FUNCTION_NAME-cloudformation-template.json`
The parameter to edit is: `Resources.LambdaFunction.Properties.Runtime = "nodejs14.x"

Answer (score 1):

Currently (26 July 2021), AWS Amplify only support NodeJS ver 12.x. Please see the [Supported Lambda runtimes](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function#supported-lambda-runtimes) paragraph in the Amplify Docs for reference.

Comment: That's interesting because my local CLI NodeJS version is 14.x and my `amplify mock function` calls work without errors with my 14.x code. 
Also, when I edit the NodeJS version in the Lambda console, it directly tells me to use the latest 14.x: [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/ZwNUkxc), but I get that this may just be a difference between the CLI and the console.

Thanks for the reply. This makes sense I guess..